# Overriding and Type Extension

Tags: oop, ada

Just hoping someone can explain why my program is defaulting to the Move_Piece procedure for the Piece Type, and not the Move_Piece procedure for the Pond type when I attempt to move a pond. When I pass a variable of Pond type to the Move_Piece procedure, "Using basic Move_Piece" gets printed instead of "1". Why is this?

I am using Ada 2005, in case that wasnt obvious by the overriding keyword. I hope I have not provided too little of information. Thanks!

chess_types.ads:

```
package Chess_Types is
  type Color is (Black, White);
  type Piece is tagged
    record
     Name : String (1 .. 3) := "   ";
     Alive : Boolean := False;
     Team  : Color;
     Coordinate : Integer;
  end record;
  procedure Move_Piece(P: in out Piece);
  -- Board Types
  type Board_Row is array (Positive range 1 .. 8) of Piece;
  type Board_Type is array (Positive range 1 .. 8) of Board_Row;
end Chess_Types;
```

chess_types.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Chess_Types is
   procedure Move_Piece(P: in out Piece) is
   begin
      Put_Line("Using basic Move_Piece");
   end Move_Piece;
end Chess_types;
```

chess_types-piece_types.ads:

```
package Chess_Types.Piece_Types is

   type Pond is new Piece with
      record
         First_Move : Boolean := True;
      end record;
   overriding
   procedure Move_Piece(Po: in out Pond);

   type Rook is new Piece with null record;
      overriding
   procedure Move_Piece(Ro: in out Rook);

   type Knight is new Piece with null record;
      overriding
   procedure Move_Piece(Kn: in out Knight);

   type Bishop is new Piece with null record;
      overriding
   procedure Move_Piece(Bi: in out Bishop);

   type Queen is new Piece with null record;
      overriding
   procedure Move_Piece(Qu: in out Queen);

   type King is new Piece with null record;
      overriding
   procedure Move_Piece(Ki: in out King);
end Chess_Types.Piece_Types;
```

chess_types-piece_types.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Chess_Types.Piece_Types is
--   Possible_Moves : array (Integer range 1 .. 100) of Integer range 11 .. 88;
   procedure Move_Piece(Po: in out Pond) is
   begin
      Put_Line("1");
   end Move_Piece;

   procedure Move_Piece(Ro: in out Rook) is
   begin
      Put_Line("2");
   end Move_Piece;

   procedure Move_Piece(Kn: in out Knight) is
   begin
      Put_Line("3");
   end Move_Piece;

   procedure Move_Piece(Bi: in out Bishop) is
   begin
      Put_Line("4");
   end Move_Piece;

   procedure Move_Piece(Qu: in out Queen) is
   begin
      Put_Line("5");
   end Move_Piece;

   procedure Move_Piece(Ki: in out King) is
   begin
      Put_Line("6");
   end Move_Piece;
end Chess_types.Piece_Types;
```

chess.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Print_Things;
with Adjust_Board;
with Chess_Types;
with Chess_Types.Piece_Types;
use Ada.Text_IO;
use Print_Things;
use Adjust_Board;
use Chess_Types;
use Chess_Types.Piece_Types;

procedure Chess is
   Board : Board_Type;
   Move  : String (1 .. 5);
   Move_From : Integer range 11 .. 88;
   Move_To   : Integer range 11 .. 88;
begin

   -- Initialize and Print default board
   Initialize_Board(Board);
   Print_Board(Board);

   -- Get the move
   Put_Line("Select a move:");
   Move := Get_Line;
   while move /= "Q" loop
      Move_From := Integer'Value(Move(Move'First .. Move'First + 1));
      Move_To := Integer'Value(Move(Move'First + 3 .. Move'Last));
      --   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Move_From) & " to" & Integer'Image(Move_To));

      -- Associate the move with a piece
      for I in Board'Range(1) loop
         for J in Board'Range(1) loop
            if Move_From = Board(I)(J).Coordinate then
               Move_Piece(Board(I)(J));
            end if;
         end loop;
      end loop;
      -- Print the Board
      Print_Board(Board);
      -- Get the move
      Put_Line("Select a move:");
      Move := Get_Line;
   end loop;


end Chess;
```

adjust_board.adb:

```
with Chess_Types;
use Chess_Types;
with Chess_Types.Piece_Types;
use Chess_Types.Piece_Types;
package body Adjust_Board is

   procedure Initialize_Board(Board: in out Board_Type) is
      -- Define White Chess Pieces
      WP1   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 12, True);
      WP2   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 22, True);
      WP3   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 32, True);
      WP4   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 42, True);
      WP5   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 52, True);
      WP6   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 62, True);
      WP7   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 72, True);
      WP8   : Pond := ("wP ", True, White, 82, True);
      WR1   : Rook := ("wRk", True, White, 11);
      WR2   : Rook := ("wRk", True, White, 81);
      WK1   : Knight := ("wKn", True, White, 21);
      WK2   : Knight := ("wKn", True, White, 71);
      WB1   : Bishop := ("wBi", True, White, 31);
      WB2   : Bishop := ("wBi", True, White, 61);
      WQ    : Queen := ("wQu", True, White, 41);
      WK    : King := ("wKi", True, White, 51);

      -- Define Black Chess Pieces
      BP1   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 17, True);
      BP2   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 27, True);
      BP3   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 37, True);
      BP4   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 47, True);
      BP5   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 57, True);
      BP6   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 67, True);
      BP7   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 77, True);
      BP8   : Pond := ("bP ", True, Black, 87, True);
      BR1   : Rook := ("bRk", True, Black, 18);
      BR2   : Rook := ("bRk", True, Black, 88);
      BK1   : Knight := ("bKn", True, Black, 28);
      BK2   : Knight := ("bKn", True, Black, 78);
      BB1   : Bishop := ("bBi", True, Black, 38);
      BB2   : Bishop := ("bBi", True, Black, 68);
      BQ    : Queen := ("bQu", True, Black, 48);
      BK    : King := ("bKi", True, Black, 58);

   begin
      -- Initialize Chess Board
      Board(1)(1) := Piece(WR1);
      Board(8)(1) := Piece(WR2);
      Board(2)(1) := Piece(WK1);
      Board(7)(1) := Piece(WK1);
      Board(3)(1) := Piece(WB1);
      Board(6)(1) := Piece(WB1);
      Board(4)(1) := Piece(WQ);
      Board(5)(1) := Piece(WK);
      Board(1)(2) := Piece(WP1);
      Board(2)(2) := Piece(WP2);
      Board(3)(2) := Piece(WP3);
      Board(4)(2) := Piece(WP4);
      Board(5)(2) := Piece(WP5);
      Board(6)(2) := Piece(WP6);
      Board(7)(2) := Piece(WP7);
      Board(8)(2) := Piece(WP8);

      Board(1)(8) := Piece(BR1);
      Board(8)(8) := Piece(BR2);
      Board(2)(8) := Piece(BK1);
      Board(7)(8) := Piece(BK1);
      Board(3)(8) := Piece(BB1);
      Board(6)(8) := Piece(BB1);
      Board(4)(8) := Piece(BQ);
      Board(5)(8) := Piece(BK);
      Board(1)(7) := Piece(BP1);
      Board(2)(7) := Piece(BP2);
      Board(3)(7) := Piece(BP3);
      Board(4)(7) := Piece(BP4);
      Board(5)(7) := Piece(BP5);
      Board(6)(7) := Piece(BP6);
      Board(7)(7) := Piece(BP7);
      Board(8)(7) := Piece(BP8);
   end Initialize_Board;
end Adjust_Board;
```

Comment: You should show us the place where you make the call to Move_Piece. In Ada, the caller decides whether a call is dispatching or not. Chances are you are calling directly on the Piece-type and not Piece'Class, which would be dispatching.

Comment: `Move_Piece(Board(I)(J))` is of Board_Type declared in chess_types.ads. I and J is just for looping through the two dimensional array until the Piece is found with the same coordinates on the chess board as the one the player chose to move. I also tried `Board(I)(J).Move_Piece` but that had a similar effect. If this isnt enough I suppose I can copy more code related to the call.

Comment: The type declaration of Board, and how you populate the array would also help. (But since Piece'Class is an indefinite type, I guess it's declared as an array of Piece, which would explain why it doesn't dispatch)

Comment: Alright, I added chess.adb and adjust_board.adb which include the a more detailed view of how I call Move_Piece and how I populate the Board array. I hope this helps

Comment: In order to populate the array, you have a type conversion to Piece for all entries. This means you loose type information, and dispatching won't work. For dispatching to work when you have an array like this, you'll need to use access types. An alternative is to rewrite your type structure to be a variant record (with a default alternative to make it definite).

Comment: How would one go about defining the array to consist of multiple types, albeit related ones through tagging like I am trying to do here? Could you give me some type of code examples to go off of?

Comment: Just one other note: I think that instead of "Pond" you mean "Pawn".  Putting a pond on your chessboard is going to get it all wet and make a big mess.

Comment: Haha wow, I cant believe that slipped by me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In chess_types.ads, add

```
type Piece_Acc is access all Piece'Class;
```

Board_Row needs to be an array of Piece_Acc:

```
type Board_Row is array (1..8) of Piece_Acc;
```

You really want the elements in your array to be Piece'Class, but that doesn't work, since the compiler can't tell at that point what types might be derived from Piece and what their memory size is, so it wouldn't be able to set up an array.  So it needs to be an access type instead.  (In C# or Java, all objects are automatically access types [pointers] whether you want it or not.  In Ada you need to tell it when you want things to be pointers.)  Then when you set things up in adjust_board.adb, you'd say things like

```
Board(1)(1) := new Rook' (WR1);
```

and so on, in order to create the access object.

[Also, this will cause everything else in Board that isn't initialized to be initialized to null.  If you want to initialize it to some other Piece that indicates "no piece", you'll need to assign to the unused spaces in the Board yourself.]

But once all that's done, when you say

```
Board(I)(J).Move_Piece;  -- same as Board(I)(J).all.Move_Piece;
```

or

```
Move_Piece(Board(I)(J).all);
```

the type of Board(I)(J).all is a class-wide type, so it will dispatch to the correct Move_Piece like you want.

Note that if when you allocate things yourself with "new", you also have to be responsible for deallocation to avoid memory leaks (unless everything is allocated only once, and then you don't really care).  The best way to do that involves controlled types, i.e. making Piece derived from Ada.Finalization.Controlled.

MORE: A way to avoid dealing with the access and allocation/deallocation stuff yourself might be to use Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors instead of an array:

```
subtype Board_Index is Integer range 1 .. 64;
package Chessboard is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors (Board_Index, Piece'Class);
```

This package doesn't allow multidimensional-type indexes, so you'd need to compute a single index yourself (in the range 1..64 or 0..63), or instantiate Indefinite_Vectors twice which I think is clunky.  But this should eliminate the need to do your own allocations, and I think it also does the deallocations for you when the container is destroyed.

Comment: P.S. I'm lousy at naming things, so if you want a different name than Piece_Acc please feel free.

Comment: Wouldnt the elements (WR1, WR2, etc) need to be declared differently as well?

Comment: @halexh: No, declaring it as a Rook, etc., is what you want.  And I think I messed up the "new"; it should be `Board(1)(1) := new Rook' (WR1);`.  The compiler recognizes that Rook is a type in Piece'Class and it's OK for an `access all Piece'Class` to be an access to a Rook.  I've edited my response.

Comment: I'd call an access-to-thing `Thing_P`.

Comment: If you use `Indefinite_Vectors`, you'll have to create an `Empty_Square` type. I'd think this would be a lot more trouble than using the access type. And, in this case, you know exactly when to deallocate a `Piece`.