# Circular dependency between new vector package and procedure

Tags: ada

I am attempting to understand how to fix this circular dependency. All the examples I can find online suggest using a limited with, but then they demonstrate the use with two basic types, whereas this is a bit more advanced. The circular dependency is between the two files below. I thought it was between `package Chessboard ...` and the `Piece` type, but now I am not so sure. Attempting to put the `package Chessboard ...` line within chess_types.ads after the `Piece` type is declared and removing the `use` and `with` of Chessboard results in an error: `this primitive operation is declared too late` for the `Move` procedure. I am stuck on how to get out of this dependency. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

chessboard.ads:

```
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors;
use Ada.Containers;
with Chess_Types;
use Chess_Types;

package Chessboard is new Indefinite_Vectors(Board_Index, Piece'Class);
```

chess_types.ads:

```
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors;
use Ada.Containers;
with Chessboard;
use Chessboard;

package Chess_Types is
   subtype Board_Index is Integer range 1 .. 64;
   type Color is (Black, White);
   type Piece is tagged
      record
         Name : String (1 .. 3) := "   ";
         Alive : Boolean := False;
         Team  : Color;
         Coordinate : Integer;
      end record;
   procedure Move_Piece(Board: in Vector; P: in Piece; Move_To: in Integer);
end Chess_Types;
```

More Code for question in comments:

Chess_Types.Piece_Types.ads:

```
package Chess_Types.Piece_Types is

   type Pawn is new Piece with
      record
         First_Move : Boolean := True;
      end record;
   overriding
   procedure Move_Piece(Board: in CB_Vector'Class; Po: in Pawn; Move_To: in Board_Index);

   -- Other piece types declared here

end Chess_Types.Piece_Types;
```

Chess_Types.Piece_Types.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Chess_Types.Piece_Types is
   procedure Move_Piece(Board: in CB_Vector'Class; Po: in Pawn; Move_To: in Board_Index) is
      Index_From, Index_To : Board_Index;
      Move_From : Board_Index := Po.Coordinate;
   begin
      -- Obtain locations of Pawn to move from (Index_From) and to (Index_To)
      -- in terms of the single dimension vector
      for I in Board.First_Index .. Board.Last_Index loop
         if Board.Element(I).Coordinate = Move_From then
            Index_From := I;
         end if;
         if Board.Element(I).Coordinate = Move_To then
            Index_To := I;
         end if;
      end loop;

      -- Determine if the requested move is legal, and if so, do the move.
      -- More possibilties to be entered, very primitive for simple checking.
      if Move_To - Move_From = 2 and then Po.First_Move = True then
         Board.Swap(I => Index_From, J => Index_To); -- "actual for "Container" must be a variable"
         Board.Element(Index_From).First_Move := False; -- "no selector for "First_Move" for type "Piece'Class"
      elsif Move_To - Po.Coordinate = 1 then
         Board.Swap(Index_From, Index_To); -- "actual for "Container" must be a variable"
      end if;

      -- Test to make sure we are in the right Move_Piece procedure
      Put_Line("1");

   end Move_Piece;

-- Other piece type move_piece procedures defined here

end Chess_types.Piece_Types;
```

As a note to understand further, the Coordinate component of each piece correspond to [ICCF numeric notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICCF_numeric_notation), which is two digits, so there needs to be some type of conversion between the vector and the ICCF notation, hence the reason for the whole for loop at the start.

Comment: Aaack.  I think I owe you an apology since I suggested Indefinite_Vectors earlier, but I didn't try it and I didn't anticipate this problem.

Comment: No - that was a great suggestion because of all the properties of that container make it so much easier. It made printing the chess board much more simple, and it has made the concept of moving the chess pieces easier, which I was just implementing until I ran into this.

Comment: Why do you _Need_ to use overriding ?

Comment: To apply OOP principles to each chess piece. I want to demonstrate some type of inheritance from the Piece type to each actual piece.

Comment: My Solution will apply inheritance and polymorphism - but each to their own i guess.

Comment: I guess it was also because I wanted to avoid using pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one.  It looks like `limited with` and generics don't play nice together.  The only way to make it work is to go back to using your own access type:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
use Ada.Containers;
limited with Chess_Types;
use Chess_Types;

package Chessboard_Package is
    subtype Board_Index is Integer range 1 .. 64;
    type Piece_Acc is access all Piece'Class;      
    package Chessboard is new Vectors(Board_Index, Piece_Acc);
end Chessboard_Package;
```

I had to put the instantiation into a new package, and move the Board_Index there too.  Also, I changed it to Vectors since Piece_Acc is a *definite* type and there's no point in using Indefinite_Vectors.  But in any event, this defeats the purpose.  I'm just not sure Ada gives you a way to do what you want with two packages like this.

Even doing it in one package is not easy:

```
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors;
use Ada.Containers;

package Chess_Types is

   subtype Board_Index is Integer range 1 .. 64;
   type Color is (Black, White);
   type Piece is tagged record ... end record;

   type CB_Vector is tagged;
   procedure Move_Piece (Board   : in CB_Vector'Class;
                         P       : in Piece;
                         Move_To : in Board_Index);

   package Chessboard is new Indefinite_Vectors(Board_Index, Piece'Class);

   type CB_Vector is new Chessboard.Vector with null record;

end Chess_Types;
```

This compiles, but I had to add extra stuff to get around some of the language rules (in particular, when you instantiate a generic, that "freezes" all prior tagged types so that you can no longer declare a new primitive operation of the type); also, I had to make the Board parameter a classwide type to avoid running into the rule about primitive operations of multiple tagged types.

Comment: The problem with the second possible solution is that I no longer have overriding Move_Piece procedures for the other pieces, because of `CB_Vector'Class`. Damn - I really wanted to use that Vector container too. It seems like the easier way to do this.

Comment: Not true.  It's still a primitive operation of Piece.  You should still be able to override Move_Piece for other types derived from Piece, and dispatch to it.  OK, one thing I may have forgotten to mention: when you declare Move_Piece for your other types, in Chess_Types.Piece_Types, you'll also have to change the Board parameter to CB_Vector'Class, or else the profile won't match and it won't be overriding.

Comment: You are correct. I wasn't interpreting the compile error I was getting correctly. One other question. The Pawn piece has its own component First_Move that the other pieces do not have. I have compiled correctly, but now, after these changes when I attempt to reference that component I get a error: `no selector "First_Move" for type "Piece'Class" defined ...`. But I can reference the other components defined in the Piece type. Do I need to update the definition of the pieces? I have confirmed it is utilizing the correct Move_Piece procedure through put_line statements though.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, this will do what you want.

```
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors;
use Ada.Containers;

package Chess_Types is

   subtype Board_Index is Integer range 1 .. 64;
   type Color is (Black, White);
   type Piece is abstract tagged
      record
         Name : String (1 .. 3) := "   ";
         Alive : Boolean := False;
         Team  : Color;
         Coordinate : Board_Index;
      end record;
   type Piece_Ptr is access all Piece'Class;

   package Chessboard is new Indefinite_Vectors(Board_Index, Piece_Ptr);

   procedure Move_Piece (Board   : in Chessboard.Vector;
                         P       : in Piece'Class;
                         Move_To : in Board_Index) is abstract;
end Chess_Types;
```

NOTES:

1. `Piece` is now abstract, as is the `Move_Piece` method. This will mean you now need to derive your other piece types (package `piece_type-rook.ads`, with a `move_piece` method for `rook`) etc...
2. Chessboard now contains pointers (Class wide pointers), beware allocating, deallocating, deep copy, shallow copy issues when using it.
3. You should now be able to call `Move_Piece` on any dereference of a `piece_ptr` and have it dispatch to the correct method.
4. The `Move_To` parameter is now the same type as the `Board_Index`. (`Coordinate` also brought in line) -- this seems a bit clunky, perhaps rethink this. (Row & Column Indices defining a 2D array perhaps? --No need for Indefinite_Vectors)

Comment: No, that won't work.  The idea is that Move_Piece is supposed to be an operation of type Piece that can be overridden for derived types Pawn, Knight, etc.  To do this, Move_Piece has to be a "primitive operation" of Piece.  Since you've declared the parameter P of Move_Piece to be Piece'Class, not Piece, it is not a primitive operation and cannot be overridden, and dispatching to Move_Piece won't work.  Unfortunately, changing Piece'Class to Piece causes an error because of the freezing rules.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557803/overriding-and-type-extension?noredirect=1#comment25547425_17557803) I asked yesterday will probably give more detail as to where I was heading with this question, which will hopefully explain ajb's comment in more detail

Comment: Please also note that this is a followup question to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557803/overriding-and-type-extension), and I suggested Indefinite_Vectors as a way to _avoid_ using pointers.

Comment: Well, I solved the circular dependency, and there is nothing in this question about having to use overriding! - Let me think about this some more.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question in the comment:

To use First_Move, the procedure has to know that it's a Pawn.  If the object is declared with type Piece'Class, you can't access components that are defined only for one of the derived types.  (That's true in most OO languages.)  This may indicate a flaw in your design; if you have a procedure that takes a Piece'Class as a parameter, but you want to do something that makes sense only for a Pawn, then maybe you should add another operation to your Piece that does a default action for most pieces (perhaps it does nothing) and then override it for Pawn.  Other possibilities are to use a type conversion:

```
procedure Something (P : Piece'Class) is ...

    if Pawn(P).First_Move then ...
```

which will raise an exception if P isn't a Pawn.  If you want to test first, you can say "if P in Pawn".  I sometimes write code like:

```
    if P in Pawn then
        declare
            P_Pawn : Pawn renames Pawn(P);
        begin
            if P_Pawn.First_Move then ...
        end;
    end if;
```

But defining a new polymorphic operation is preferable.  (Note: I haven't tested the above code, hope I didn't make a syntax error somewhere.)

Comment: I guess thats what I was trying to say in the question - the procedure does know its a pawn. This is actually in regards to Move_Piece procedure for the Pawn. I know it knows its pawn, because when I attempt to call Move_Piece on a object that is of type Pawn (its declared as a Pawn and not a Piece), it prints something specific to that procedure and not the other Move_Piece procedures. Could it be something else?

Comment: Are you saying that inside Move_Piece that has a Pawn as a parameter, it won't let you look at First_Move?  I think maybe I need to see the exact code, but the error message indicates that you're trying to select First_Move on a variable or parameter that is declared as Piece'Class, not Pawn.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. I have included the related code, and the compile errors as comments next to the corresponding line. Hopefully you can explain another issue you will see in the comments

Comment: OK, I see.  Yes, the compiler knows "Po" is a Pawn, but it doesn't know that Board.Element(Index_From) is a Pawn.  Actually, are you sure it's a Pawn?  If you do it after you call Swap, isn't Board.Element(Index_From) going to be a blank space?  And Board.Element(Index_To) should be the Pawn?  I'm not certain just what's correct, but in either case, the compiler doesn't know what goes on inside Swap so it has no way to know that Board.Element(Index) is going to be a Pawn.  So here you have to help it by doing a type conversion.

Comment: As for the error "actual for Container must be a variable": this is because the Container, which is actually CB_Vector (which is derived from the Vector), is an IN parameter but you're trying to modify it.  Changing this to IN OUT in all the Move_Piece routines should fix it.

Comment: Within the Pawn's Move_Piece procedure, why can I compare things of an element within board, but not assign things? For example, I can do `if Board.Element(Index).Coordinate = 10 then` but I cannot do `Board.Element(Index).Coordinate := 10`. In that case I get `left hand side of assignment must be a variable` .. But it is a variable? Why does the compiler think otherwise?

Comment: Element(Index) is a function call.  Function calls return values, not references to variables or other objects.  (If some other function returned an "access T", you could modify the T that the function result points to, but Element doesn't return an access.)  The Indefinite_Vectors package has a Replace_Element procedure that might do what you want.